# why graph api like count missing

Tags: facebook-graph-api, count, facebook-like

Graph API is not reporting number of likes (shares) anymore, or is at least inconstant about it:

Here likes are missing:
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/12/25/pope-christmas-eve-mass-god_n_2361399.html

but present on IMDB:
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1853728/

also old output with number of shares and comments can be found for older web pages.

Is this a problem with roll-out or is this a bug? From what I can gather output started to change around 20th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. FQL Query is an alternative that still works. Here's an example:

```
select comment_count, share_count, like_count from link_stat where url = "http://techcrunch.com/2011/04/12/facebook-comments-now-on-over-50k-sites-get-more-social-with-latest-upgrade/"
```

Try the API Explorer here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select%20comment_count%2C%20share_count%2C%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Ftechcrunch.com%2F2011%2F04%2F12%2Ffacebook-comments-now-on-over-50k-sites-get-more-social-with-latest-upgrade%2F%22

However I would love it if they changed the Graph API to return share counts and comment counts again.

This official Facebook doc (developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) still recommends using the Graph API for comment counts, however it does not seem to work with new pages like this one: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://techcrunch.com/2012/12/27/the-last-imac-question-mark/

Comment: There is a bug report for this on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/180781098727185?browse=search_50dda74e1870c8d60275326

It has been set to low priority :(

Comment: Facebook changed priority to medium, so hopefully it will be resolved shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20comment_count%2C%20share_count%2C%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2013%2F01%2F30%2Ffacebook-twitter-blackberry-10%2F%22

Which will yield results like

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "comment_count": 3,
         "share_count": 91,
         "like_count": 5
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been accepted as bug few days ago,

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/180781098727185?browse=search_50dda74e1870c8d60275326

hope they resolve this in short future